# Access to media folder

Tags: android, storage, read-write

Which permission is required to read/write files inside folder
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/packagename/
in Android 11 and Android 13?
It is not for my app, for the folder of another app.
Do you have a little example (some lines of code) for me?

Comment: If `packagename` is for your app, you do not need any permissions.

Comment: The packagename is from another app.

Comment: You can browse all folders of other apps but will not see their files unless you go for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: If you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCMRNT_TREE for Android media directory you can read all package dirs and the files in it. No permissions needed.